# Do printers really have hard disks or any kind of storage in them?

Tags: security, printing, printer, privacy

I keep hearing about how insecure it is to use printers to print any kind of sensitive material, such as Bitcoin private keys. Allegedly because they "store all printed pages on internal storage". But is this really the case?

Isn't this just for big, expensive, industrial printers? And even then, it seems a bit weird to me. Why would this be done in the first place?

I have a Canon PIXMA iP2700 purchased 8 years ago. Nothing in its specs seem to indicate that it has *any* kind of memory whatsoever. Is this unusual?

Comment: do a quick test ... print a 20 page document ... when the first page starts printing, disconnect wifi or lan from the computer ... see how many pages were stored in the printer

Comment: @jsotola this is not a great test, as its possible to hold a lot of pages in memory, and depends extremely heavily on what was printed.  You can fit an aweful lot of plain text pages in even an obsurdly low 1 megabyte of memory.

Comment: @davidgo exactly ... the printer will most likely print all 20 pages ... that easily answers the question `Do printers really have hard disks or any kind of storage in them?`

Comment: @jsotola I think by storage the OP was likely meaning non-volatile storage.

Answer (score 0):

It is "relatively" safe to print this stuff out your PIXMA iP2700 printer as it most likely does not save a copy of the data to any kind of disk or ROM.  (the printer most likely has some read-write storage, but it will be small, slow and used for the printer firmware - not rendering pages.

Where you would need to look at storage is in printers which either (a) older printers that have advanced rendering in them or (b) high volume office printers and above.  The bar for printers with hard drives is probably higher then you would use in a typical home environment but lower then you would expect in a corporate environment.    One office of about 20 staff I worked in had a shared office printer which had a hard drive.  (It was a security risk I pointed out to them).   You are more likely to run into this with older printers.

Another thing to be mindful of is color printers - Almost all color laser printers will print some yellow dots/markings unique to the printer (this was likely implmented at the behest of governments - https://www.eff.org/pages/list-printers-which-do-or-do-not-display-tracking-dots  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Identification_Code )